# How to write complex dapps

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, go-ethereum

How does one create a more complex dapp that needs features like recurring jobs, generating random numbers, trigger e-mails, etc. (without using something like oraclize).

What's the flow for an app like this? You write the app in a programming language like Go, deploy your own node and interact with your deployed contract(written in solidity) through RPC? That way you can send a random number to the function/contract from your off-chain backend that's then used in the contract?

Does it make sense to keep on the blockchain only the the features that need to be transparent to the users and have the rest of the app functionalities on a backend like Go?

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, I think that you ask too manu questions and actually, you don't have very clear what you want. However, I'm going to answer them.

> How does one create a more complex dapp

Developing more complex Smart Contracts.

> What's the flow for an app like this?

1. You develop the Smart Contract
2. You deploy it
3. You interact with it

> Does it make sense to keep on the blockchain only the the features
>   that need to be transparent to the users and have the rest of the app
>   functionalities on a backend like Go?

It dependes on your case of use

Answer (score 0):

As Urko said, there is many questions and you shall be specific.
You know a good way to defeat your problem is to divide them and conquer.

You can use many languages, but my prefer is C/C++ but many people are using Go, Python and specially NodeJS.

Firstly first, get to know what you are going to do, what you want to do.

I am backing up [Urko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832787/10251345).
Read documentation and sample files such as Solidity can help you to create Smart Contracts and then Deploy and Intract with them.
I call DApps, any software which can work with Blockchains.